# Trying to install Rainlendar-lite in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, gpu-driver

Following @vanadium 's instructions, Rainlendar installed with no error message. However, I get the following screen tearing:

[image: rainlendar screen shot]

I have an nvidia care, but am using the nouveau driver. Could it be related to this?